# Como inserir os valores e sua frequência em um data.frame, a partir de um conjunto obtido pelo SAMPLE?

Tags: r

Primeiro obter uma sequência de valores aleatórios

```
set.seed(100)
estat <- sample(1:20, replace=TRUE)
estat
 [1]  7  6 12  2 10 10 17  8 11  4 13 18  6  8 16 14  5  8  8 14
```

A ideia seria:
1 haveria como impor ao SAMPLE que a soma dos valores obtidos seja 200 ?
2 ordenar os valores e suas frequências em formato de tabela

O intuito é montar uma tabela estatística para cálculo simples de Média, Variância, DP, Desvio Médio, CV, Assimetria e Curtose.

Assim, todos os resultados seriam realizados e guardados na tabela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seja X_1, X_2, ..., X_n uma sequência de números. Seja X = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n. Se eu dividir o valor de cada X_i por X, a soma X_1/X + X_2/X + ... + X_n/X sempre terá valor 1. Isto é um tipo de normalização. Se eu multiplicar cada lado desta igualdade por 200, vou ter o resultado que procuro.

Portanto, basta aplicar esta ideia no `R` para ter o resultado desejado. Eu criei uma função chamada `amostra` que faz isto.

```
amostra <- function(x=1:20, size=20, replace=TRUE, limit=200){
  estat <- sample(x, size, replace=replace)
  estat <- round(estat/sum(estat)*limit)
  if (sum(estat) == limit){
    return(estat)
  } else {
    return(c(estat[1:(size-1)], limit-sum(estat[1:(size-1)])))
  }
}

x <- amostra(1:20, 20, limit=200)
x
[1]  4 12 12 13 12 13  2 12 11  2 14  7 12 17 12  3 11  5 11 15
sum(x)
[1] 200
```

Esta função tem 4 argumentos:

`x`: os possíveis valores que a amostra pode tomar (inteiros de 1 a 20)

`size`: o tamanho da amostra a ser criada (o padrão é 20)

`replace`: indica (o padrão é haver reposição)

`limit`: o limite total da soma (o padrão é 200)

Devido a problemas de arredondamento, eu fiz um pequeno truque no algoritmo. Ele sorteia n elementos da amostra e testa se a soma é igual a `limit`. Se for igual, ele retorna a amostra procurada.

Se for diferente, o último elemento é determinado pela fórmula `limit-sum(estat[1:(size-1)])`, que é a diferença entre o somatório-alvo e a soma dos n-1 primeiros elementos da amostra.

Se isto não fosse feito, não haveria garantia da soma final dos elementos ser igual a `limit`.

O comando `table` ordena os valores e suas respectivas frequências:

```
table(x)
x
 2  3  4  5  7 11 12 13 14 15 17 
 2  1  1  1  1  3  6  2  1  1  1
```

A partir disto, enfim, é possível calcular as estatísticas desejadas, criando um data frame com as respostas:

```
as.data.frame(table(x))
    x Freq
1   2    2
2   3    1
3   4    1
4   5    1
5   7    1
6  11    3
7  12    6
8  13    2
9  14    1
10 15    1
11 17    1
```

Comment: Marcus, muito obrigado !!! Muito boa a estruturação e explicação. Guardarei como CMD para posteriori.

Minha ideia era poder usar o 'limitador' apenas para facilitar os cáculos de Média e os demais. Porém, precisava obter os dados das frequências (como mostrado na 2a linha do output table(x)) como uma nova coluna.

Como capturar esses resultados e pô-los em um data.frame, como uma coluna  ?
xi fi
2 2
3 1

Comment: Veja a edição que realizei.

Comment: Marcus, perfeito !!! 
Quero montar toda uma tabela estatística para os alunos, passo a passo, para guardar o histórico dos cálculos realizados, montando coluna por coluna, sendo dados os valores de x e suas frequências.